# OpenCV SVM train_auto Insufficient Memory

Tags: opencv, image-processing, classification, svm, training-data

This is my first post here so I hope to be able to ask my question properly :-)

I want to do "elephant detection" by classifying color samples (I was inspired by [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-5281-2013-46/fulltext.html)). This is the pipeline of my "solution" until the training of the classifier:

1. Loading a set of 4 training images (all containing an elephant), and then splitting them in two images: one containing the environment surrounding the elephant (the "background"), and one containing the elephant (the "foreground");
2. Mean shift segmentation of the backgrounds and the foregrounds;
3. RGB -> Luv color space conversion and pixel values extraction (in order to fill a Mat object with 3 columns and a number of rows equal to the number of samples);
4. SVM training with an RBF Kernel by calling train_auto method.

So, the problem arises in this last step: after a while (a few hours), I get the following error message:

### OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 22165936 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file xxx\alloc.cpp, line 52

### terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

### what(): xxx\alloc.cpp:52:error: (-4) Failed to allocate 22165936 bytes in function OutOfMemoryError

My training samples are a [3 columns x 1,385,235 rows] CV_32FC1 Mat object. I don't believe that this data structure is too large, isn't it? I've 16 GB of RAM, and I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and Codeblocks.

However, this is the source code:

```
//Loading Background & Foreground Training Images
Mat train_00_background = imread("training_set/train_00_background.png");
cvtColor(train_00_background, train_00_background, CV_BGR2BGRA);
oclMat t_00_bg;
t_00_bg.upload(train_00_background);

(...)


Mat train_00_foreground = imread("training_set/train_00_foreground.png");
cvtColor(train_00_foreground, train_00_foreground, CV_BGR2BGRA);
oclMat t_00_fg;
t_00_fg.upload(train_00_foreground);

(...)

//COLOR SEGMENTATION by MEAN SHIFT CLUSTERING
meanShiftSegmentation(t_00_bg, train_00_background_clustered, 5, 5, 50, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + TermCriteria::EPS, 5, 1));

(...)

//CV_8UC3 -> CV_32FC3
train_00_background_clustered.convertTo(train_00_background_clustered, CV_32FC3);

(...)

//Normalization
train_00_background_clustered *= 1./255;

(...)

//RGB -> Luv
cvtColor(train_00_background_clustered, train_00_background_clustered, CV_BGR2Luv);

(...)

//COLOR LIST EXTRACTION FROM BACKGROUND AND FOREGROUND
//colorListBg_00 is a 3 x NumberOfColors CV_32FC1 Mat
extractColorList(train_00_background_clustered, colorListBg_00);

// Memory release
train_00_background_clustered.release(); 

(...)

//Color List concatenation
//background
colorListBg_00.copyTo(colorList);
colorList.push_back(colorListBg_01);
(...)
Size s = colorList.size();
int s1 = s.height;

//foreground  
colorList.push_back(colorListFg_00);
(...)
s = colorList.size();
int s2 = s.height - s1;

// ASSIGNING THE LABELS
Mat labelsBg(s1, 1, CV_32FC1, -1.0);
Mat labelsFg(s2, 1, CV_32FC1, 1.0);
Mat labels;
labelsBg.copyTo(labels);
labels.push_back(labelsFg);

// SVM TRAINING
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON );

CvSVM SVM;   
SVM.train_auto(colorList, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params, 2);
```

Thank you for paying attention towards this question.

Comment: Note that a 32 bits program cannot use those 16GB of memory. 64 bits programs rarely crash on an out-of-memory; they just swap like crazy.

Comment: well, so I have to try by recompiling my program. Just for curiosity: my error says that it isn't possible to allocate 22 megabytes of data... Is this a limitation of 32 bit memory allocation? I did believe that maximum threshold was of 4 gigabytes!
Thank you anyway :-)

Comment: The problem is the allocation of an _extra_ 22 MB, in a contiguous memory block.

Comment: can you check how much memory is consumed by your whole program(s)? seems odd to me that those extra 22 MB arent allocatable, maybe you got memory problems somewhere else?

Comment: @Micka the memory consumed by my whole process @ 32 bits is about 900 megabytes; the same program compiled @ 64 bits grows until 4.6 gigabytes.

Comment: @MSalters IT WORKS at 64 bits and it doesn't crash! Thank you!
(the quality of my detection is still poor, but I'm happy anyways :D)