# OpenCV 3 SVM train with large Data

Tags: c++, machine-learning, opencv3.0

I recently switched from OpenCV 2.4.6 to 3.0.
My Code looks like this:

```
Ptr<ml::SVM> pSVM = ml::SVM::create();
pSVM->->setType(cv::ml::SVM::C_SVC);
pSVM->setKernel(cv::ml::SVM::LINEAR);
pSVM->->setC(1);

 cv::Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> TrainData = cv::ml::TrainData::create(TrainMatrix, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, Labels);
//TrainMatrix is a cv::Mat with 35000 rows and 1900 cols and float values in it. One Feature per row.
//Labels is a std::vector<int> with 35000 Elements with 1 and -1 in it.

   pSVM->trainAuto(TrainData, 10, cv::ml::SVM::getDefaultGrid(cv::ml::SVM::C), cv::ml::SVM::getDefaultGrid(cv::ml::SVM::GAMMA), cv::ml::SVM::getDefaultGrid(cv::ml::SVM::P),
            cv::ml::SVM::getDefaultGrid(cv::ml::SVM::NU), cv::ml::SVM::getDefaultGrid(cv::ml::SVM::COEF), cv::ml::SVM::getDefaultGrid(cv::ml::SVM::DEGREE), false);
```

When my program reaches the trainAuto method is crashes and in the error message stands that it cannot allocate 524395968 bytes. This number seems a little bit high. Before the crash the program consumes about 400 MB in Debug Mode.

If I put a smaller matrix (about 500 rows) in the method everything runs normally.

Has anyone same problems and knows a solution to it?

Comment: Have you tried to use `train` instead of `trainAuto`? Will that also crash?

Comment: Yes same outcome and also the same error message with the bytes

Comment: Is your program built in 32 bit?

Comment: Yes its a 32 bit visual studio express 2013 version

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605249/opencv-svm-train-auto-insufficient-memory

Comment: But with my OpenCV 2.4.6 Version of the Code everything works fine. Even with a bigger Train Matrix.
But maybe the train function fills the TrainData at the beginning of the training process, so my 400 MB would double and then the train process consumes 200 MB extra